# Agreement in a copulative clause: "... es, en sí mism(o|a), una ..."

Tags: concordancia-gramatical

I've noticed that Spanish is a bit tricky when it comes to [agreement in copular clauses](https://www.tdx.cat/bitstream/handle/10803/397778/temv.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y). The following sentence still caught me a little off-guard though:

> El deseo de una experiencia más positiva es, en sí **misma**, una experiencia negativa.

I would have expected "misma" to agree with "el deseo". As written, I'm about 50/50 between thinking that this is just how Spanish works, and "misma" agrees with the trailing "una experiencia negativa", versus this being a mistaken agreement with the preceding "una experience positiva".

Comment: I'm not sure that sentence is correct. I would have said "en sí mismo". What is actually a negative experience is the wish for a more positive experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a mistake in the source text. It's understandable, like other failures of agreement when several sentence constituents are subordinated or linked to each other in a more-or-less complicated arrangement, but it's still a mistake. Just as you expected, it should be

> *El deseo de una experiencia más positiva es, en sí **mismo**, una experiencia negativa.*

This is because the reflexive expression *sí mismo* can only refer to the previous noun phrase (the subject) as a whole (*el deseo de una experiencia más positiva*), which is headed by the masculine singular noun *deseo*; it cannot refer to the subordinate noun phrase *una experiencia más positiva*. The comment *en sí mismo* is an adverbial complement that modifies the verb, and because of how Spanish works, this means any pronouns inside it can only refer to the subject.